# How to subset dataframe based on colMeans

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as follows

```
Me    You   They   Him     She
1      4      6     3      233
82     0      2     4      122
98     2      5     2       99
```

I want to get a new dataframe which only contains those columns where the colMeans are >30 so the result should look like

```
Me    She
1     233
82    122
98    99
```

I tried something like

```
dfNew<-subset(df,colMeans(df[, 1:ncol(df)]>30))
```

but got the error

```
Error in subset.data.frame(df[, 1:ncol(df)]>  : 
  'subset' must be logical
```

Clearly don't know what Im doing.

Comment: you can try to use `dfNew<-df[colMeans(df[, 1:ncol(df)]>30), ]` instead

Comment: That doesn't give me the desired output. I don't really understnad the output but it isn't correct

Comment: you had a typo in your example, which @HubertL copied, as you probably wanted `colMeans(df[, 1:ncol(df)])>30)` (note the moved closing bracket). Otherwise the dataframe is converted to logical (by comparing each value with 30), and then `colMeans` are taken, so they would be between 0 and 1.
Also this call selects columns, while `subset` subsets by rows...
To sum up, see @HubertL's answer for correct way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
df[,colMeans(df)>30]
```

Answer (score 2):

I Think this is something that you are looking for

This step is just me creating your data.

```
Me <- c(1,82,98)
You <- c(4,0,2)
They <- c(6,5,5)
Him <- c(3,4,2)
She <- c(233,122,99)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(Me, You, They, Him, She))
```

This is what you want.

```
df[, sapply(df, mean) > 60]
```